# platformIO does not show binary sizes on build

Tags: visual-studio-code, avr, platformio

I am using VsCode with PlatformIO with a very simple program.
It compiles correctly and produces working elf and hex files.

However, unless  pio states that it checkes the sizes it does not output anything.

my configuration is the following

```
[env:release]
platform = atmelavr
board_build.mcu = atmega168A
board_build.f_cpu = 8000000L
```

running the build it just outputs:

```
Processing release (platform: atmelavr)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
HARDWARE: ATMEGA168A 8MHz,
PACKAGES: 
 - toolchain-atmelavr 1.70300.191015 (7.3.0)
LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> [had to replace link to being allowed to post]
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 0 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
No dependencies
Building in release mode
Compiling .pio\build\release\src\HMI.o
Compiling .pio\build\release\src\Oled.o
Compiling .pio\build\release\src\Segment.o
Compiling .pio\build\release\src\main.o
Linking .pio\build\release\firmware.elf
Checking size .pio\build\release\firmware.elf
Building .pio\build\release\firmware.hex
=========================================================== [SUCCESS] Took 1.95 seconds ===========================================================
```

even with running it with `-v` it shows not much more information

```
Processing release (platform: atmelavr; board_build.mcu: atmega168A; board_build.f_cpu: 8000000L)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------HARDWARE: ATMEGA168A 8MHz,
PACKAGES: 
 - toolchain-atmelavr 1.70300.191015 (7.3.0)
LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> [had to replace link to being allowed to post]
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 0 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
No dependencies
Building in release mode
avr-gcc -o .pio\build\release\src\HMI.o -c -std=gnu11 -fno-fat-lto-objects -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -mmcu=atmega168A -DF_CPU=8000000L -DPLATFORMIO=50101 -Isrc src\HMI.c
avr-gcc -o .pio\build\release\src\Oled.o -c -std=gnu11 -fno-fat-lto-objects -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -mmcu=atmega168A -DF_CPU=8000000L -DPLATFORMIO=50101 -Isrc src\Oled.c
avr-gcc -o .pio\build\release\src\Segment.o -c -std=gnu11 -fno-fat-lto-objects -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -mmcu=atmega168A 
-DF_CPU=8000000L -DPLATFORMIO=50101 -Isrc src\Segment.c
avr-gcc -o .pio\build\release\src\main.o -c -std=gnu11 -fno-fat-lto-objects -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -mmcu=atmega168A -DF_CPU=8000000L -DPLATFORMIO=50101 -Isrc src\main.c
avr-gcc -o .pio\build\release\firmware.elf -Os -mmcu=atmega168A -Wl,--gc-sections -flto -fuse-linker-plugin .pio\build\release\src\HMI.o .pio\build\release\src\Oled.o .pio\build\release\src\Segment.o .pio\build\release\src\main.o -L.pio\build\release -Wl,--start-group -lm -Wl,--end-group        
MethodWrapper(["checkprogsize"], [".pio\build\release\firmware.elf"])
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom .pio\build\release\firmware.elf .pio\build\release\firmware.hex
=========================================================== [SUCCESS] Took 1.77 seconds ===========================================================
```

I am using

- PIO extension v2.3.2
- PIO Core 5.1.1·Home 3.3.4
- platform atmelavr at 3.3.0

Manually calling `avr-size` from the the downloaded packages correctly shows the info.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: https://github.com/platformio/platformio-core/issues/59

Comment: @hcheung how does this should help? this Issue is solved for 5 years. so in theory it should work. also it seems to work on other projects that also uses atmelavr platform - could not figure out why not on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an explicit `board` config item to the config seems to fix that problem.

```
[env:release]
platform = atmelavr
board = ATmega168
board_build.mcu = atmega168A
board_build.f_cpu = 8000000L
```